# Error npm install dependencies - @iota/client deploy AWS - node api project

Tags: iota-cli, client-library

I did some local tests with my node-api-express; it works well when I send a message. So for the next step, I deployed it in ElasticBean AWS. But the console prints this error:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]
```

and the eb logs show this:

```
Error: spawn cargo ENOENT
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @iota/client@0.4.0 build:neon: `neon build --release && node scripts/move-lib.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @iota/client@0.4.0 build:neon script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried adding npmrc but no luck, any idea?